# TFS File Changed Notification

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

We have a number of files in our project and if they change they require changes to the Installers.  Developers don't seem to be aware of the knock-ons of not notifying guy that looks after the installers of a change no matter how many emails are sent about it.

We need some way of being notified if any of these files change.  I know TFS has some event subscription capabilities but haven't been able to find anything that would suit.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: +1 from me. I would also like to know about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create a custom event subscription is with the [TFS Alerts Editor](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2008/07/08/july-08-tfs-power-tool-preview.aspx) (walkthru + screenshots), which is now part of the [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).

You can find a more complete reference XPath syntax reference [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130302.aspx).